# A better resource for vector calculus than Stewart?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, vectors

I took the Math GRE Subject Test last October and tried to relearn vector calculus via the current edition of Stewart's text.

I thought, to put it lightly, that the exposition was atrocious and unmotivated, with too much of a focus on memorizing the equations needed to solve problems. I did do well on the calculus questions on the Subject Test [I think], but if I need to teach myself vector calculus again, I can't use Stewart to do it.

What do you all recommend for a good rigorous, motivational text on vector calculus? I *need* the book to cover Green's Theorem [which I've noticed, for example, Kline's text does not cover].

[This is one of those times that I *wished* Spivak covered vector calculus.]

Comment: Almost any other book. Stewart's book are the worst calculus books I have ever had to work with.

Comment: I don't know of anything on the subject that is rigorous in the sense in which mathematicians use that term.  But probably that's not what you mean.

Comment: I got a lot out of Stewart's text (pertaining to the mgre), mostly from the problem solving problems at the end of the chapters.

Comment: @MichaelHardy - By "rigorous," I mean that if requires Real Analysis and comes with some good practice problems (for an average Calc. III student), that would be a HUGE plus.

Comment: Can anyone explain why the downvote?

Comment: Do you speak Spanish? The book I learned it from is largely based on Russian texts, so it has a lot of good exercises. I think the exposition is fairly nice. But it is in Spanish. I didn't have a copy but to my surprise I found it online.

Comment: @Pp.. - I do know Spanish well enough to understand about 65% of what I read [usually have a dictionary out]. I would be interested.

Comment: It asks to log in with Facebook or something but it can be freely downloaded [here](https://www.scribd.com/doc/143307351/Analisis-de-Funciones-en-Varias-Variables-Valdes-Concepcion)

Comment: thomas calculus?

Comment: downvote reason: jealousy/envy/spite/pettiness/bitterness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I quite liked the way that [Leithold](http://libgen.org/search.php?req=leithold&lg_topic=libgen&open=0&view=simple&phrase=1&column=def) covered line integrals. It might be worth taking a look at the rest. In my opinion, better than books, is the course given in MIT, by prof. Denis Auroux, [which is available online](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02-multivariable-calculus-fall-2007/video-lectures/). I taught myself multivariable calculus using these videos before, and it was most probably the easiest subject I had in university because of that. I really recommend seeing other subjects there too.

Comment: Oh man, I've always been wary of online resources. I will have to check this out when I get back home today.

Comment: I agree with you, in general online resources aren't too good. But this is MIT we're talking about... The classes are recorded live. Sometimes students ask questions, etc. There's homework available, recitation videos, etc.

Comment: Also, I found "[Div, Grad, Curl, and All That](http://www.amazon.com/Div-Grad-Curl-All-That/dp/0393925161)" nice for some interpretations.. (for some reason library genesis isn't opening here, but you can get it there, also)

Answer (score 2):

I have some recommendations to make.

First: [Vector and Tensor Analysis with Applications, by Borisenko and Tarapov](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486638332).

This is for good old classical vector analysis, with tensor analysis to boost. It has plenty of solved problems, physical intuition and even proofs for Green, Gauss and Stokes's theorems. It does not contain over 500 hundred problems that you'd find in an usual calculus book, though. They are more carefully selected. It is a Dover title, which is financially a plus.

Second: [Mathematical Tools for Physics, by James Nearing](http://www.physics.miami.edu/~nearing/mathmethods/mathematical_methods-three.pdf).

This one's available for free. It is also a Dover title, which you can buy [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/048648212X). While it does not contain just vector calculus nor is it rigorous, it will build intuition and skill at using these tools in a variety of situations. There are two chapters devoted to Vector Calculus, the second focusing more on the computational part.

However, you can always go back to Apostol's Calculus, volume 2. It should contain everything you need (I haven't personally studied it, but that's the only calculus book I know that could combine rigor and plenty of exercises).