# Textbook for Vector Calculus

Tags: analysis, reference-request, vectors, vector-analysis

Can anyone recommend a textbook for studying vector calculus (vector analysis) only, that focuses on the theoretical mathematics behind vector calculus?

Currently, I am using vector analysis by Snider. I have also taken a look at vector calculus by Marsden. Both of these books skip a large amount of the theory behind what we are doing and why it matters.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088803/a-better-resource-for-vector-calculus-than-stewart

Answer (score 2):

Rigorous yet accessible text by J. H. Hubbard and B. B. Hubbard. Vector calculus, linear algebra, and differential forms: a unified approach with Maple 10 VP. Pearson Education, Limited, Mar. 2006.

Comment: The 2009 edition has some interesting (mostly differential geometric) additions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what level you're looking for (your question could be more precisely worded), but I recently liked the look of

- *[Vector Analysis and Cartesian Tensors](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Vector-Analysis-Cartesian-Tensors-Third/dp/0748754601)*, by Bourne and Kendall.

If you're not interested in the "Cartesian Tensors" part of the title then don't worry, that's left until the end; just focus on the first six chapters.

Answer (score 2):

A really excellent book about that argument is:

- **Vector Analysis** by Homer E. Newell, Jr - Dover Publications.

Answer (score 1):

Colley's *Vector Calculus* is very good for a more-formal-than-normal treatment of multivariable calculus. The focus is on things like partial derivatives, div, grad, curl, and multiple integrals. It could be used as a first exposure to these topics, and proofs are supplied.

For texts on a subject better described as multivariable analysis, I highly recommend Munkres's *Analysis on Manifolds* and/or Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*. These focus on topological and analytical aspects (unlike Colley) and are intended to extend the ideas of multivariable analysis to manifolds.